# Importing CSV into MySQL with PHP with first csv data as MySQL columns

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I have a csv file, that has different payment types in, it is from an EPOS system. Somethimes it doesn't include all the different payment types listed below. It looks like this

```
Payment type,Payment transactions,Payments amount
Card Payment,6,110.3
Cash,5,59.1
Online Order,2,59.4
Voucher,1,19.5
```

I am attempting to get the 'Payments amount' into a MYSQL DB via PHP, into a single row with columns which are the 'Payment type' like this

```
| transaction_id | Card Payment | Cash | Online Order | Voucher |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 12-12-19       |   110.30     |59.10 |   59.40      | 19.50   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have got the data into the DB by [following the tutorial here](https://phppot.com/php/import-csv-file-into-mysql-using-php/) but I am having a problem getting the data onto a single line. Could someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Not sure if having all of the payment types on the same row is a good idea anyway - it goes against relational design.  The main problem is what happens if a new payment type is added, or when cash becomes a thing of the past?

Comment: Ah, ok so would it then be better to have a table for each payment type or 1 table with 3 rows; ID, Date and amount?

Comment: Have 1 table with payment types (with an ID for each one) and then a table with transaction id, payment type id and amount.

Comment: Perfect thanks I'll have a go. :-)